# Java XML Parser with Sharepoint xml (http get)

Tags: java, xml, sharepoint

I need some ideas.

I'm working on an desktop notification tool for a sharepoint site.
I get the current newsfeed by http request:
domain/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed(MaxThreadCount=1)
I get the last post with all the comments and save it in a xml file like this:

```
<entry>
<element>
<name>is here an area, where a person posted</name>
<url>null</url>
<text>null</text>
</element>
<element>
<name>Kaito23</name>
<url>domain.de/something....</url>
<text>Hey, I posted something</text>
</element>
<element>Comment1</element>
<element>Comment2</element>
</entry>
```

I tried like this, but it sets a lot of null pointer

```
 File stocks = new File(xmlFile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("d:element");

        Node node = nodes.item(0);
        Element element = (Element) node;

        permalink = getValue("d:Permalink", element);
        createdTime = getValue("d:CreatedTime", element);
                statusText = getValue("d:StatusText", element);
        // creatorName = getValue("d:Name", element);
        // areaName = getValue("d:Name", element);
        imageURL = getValue("d:ImageUri", element);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any ideas for me how to fix it?

greetings Kaito

Comment: Question is not clear.. What u want to do ?? Explain clearly..What do you want to read from that XML file??

Comment: sorry >.>
I need just the name and text from the first <element>
and the name from the second <element>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File(
                "D:\\StackOverFlow\\SAXParserRelated\\src\\stocks.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("element");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if ((eElement.hasChildNodes())
                        && (eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0) != null)
                        && (eElement.getElementsByTagName("text").item(0) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(" Name : "
                            + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Text : "
                            + eElement.getElementsByTagName("text").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

let me know if u face any issues